# sed: Add new line to every file that does not have one at end of file

Tags: linux, sed

I am getting countless

> warning: no newline at end of file

From some code that was last edited in Windows.

In Linux, how can I fix all these cpp/h files and add a new line to the end of every file that does not have a new line?

I've been trying to use sed:

```
find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -print | xargs sed -i -e "$G"
```

But I haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: There is a command, `dos2unix`, that might be of assistance to you. It converts the CR+LF line ending of windows to the LF line ending of linux. Another option is to just echo (append - i.e. >> ) a newline to every relevant file.

Comment: The problem is there are far too many files to find them by hand.

Comment: Use find in that case, as with your example, just switch up sed for a different command (of course, try that command on a single file first). Both echo and dos2unix work fine with find.

Comment: I'm trying `find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -print | xargs echo >>`
 but that gives me error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'`

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a 'newline' in your command, so I guess that SF removed it. Just use echo without any arguments - it automatically adds a newline (and of course, test it out on one file before you do that - wouldn't want to see hundreds of files improperly edited) - so `echo >>` (note there is just a space between `echo` and `>>` in my command)

Comment: That's exactly what I did though. I never had any new line in the command, it was just `echo >>` and gave that error.

Comment: Ahh, well - I suppose the command does end in a newline. Just create a file with `#!/bin/sh echo >> $1` (two lines), `chmod +x`, and run your find statement passing the shell script to it. `find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -print | xargs /path/to/script.sh` - again, test on one file before applying to all...

Comment: Since you piqued my curiosity with the echo command not working without a script, there are two other solutions. `find . -type f \( -name "*.cpp" \) -print | xargs -iFILE sh -c 'echo "h" >> FILE'` seems to work quite well, as does `find . -type f \( -name "*.cpp" \) -exec sh -c 'echo >> {}' \;`

Comment: If you do "[...] | xargs echo X >>", the main shell will interpret the redirection (">>").  You will need the "sh -c" as in @cyberx86's comment.  Personally, I'd use dos2unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of `dos2unix` - which would be the ideal way, try:

```
find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -print0 | xargs -0 -iFILE sh -c 'echo >> FILE'
```

or

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -exec sh -c 'echo >> {}' \;
```

Note that redirection is always a problem - the replacement doesn't occur as desired without launching a new shell.

Since your question was about 'sed', you could also do it as:

```
find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -e '$a\
\'
```

(That is a literal new line character - not a \n or anything else - probably best done as copy and paste - as it might be rather hard to type in :).

Comment: The first one seems to insert an "h" into the file? This would break my code.

Comment: Sorry - typo - I used 'h' to test it since I was losing track of the new lines being entered - will have it edited in a second.

Comment: dos2unix did not affect all files. I used `find -type f -exec dos2unix "{}" \+` It did convert existing line endings to linux, but it did not add newlines to the ends of files that didn't have them. By the way I think you make literal newline by typing `ctrl-v` and then `ctrl-m` in linux. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/73886/631764

Comment: Actually, now I'm not sure that dos2unix failed. I based that judgment on using this code to search for files missing final newlines: `find -type f -exec sh -c '[ -z "$(sed -n "\$p" "$1")" ] && echo "$1"' _ {} \;` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4631212/631764 But it seems to be wrong. The 2nd and 3rd answers on that page give me no matches. ( `pcregrep -LMr '\n$' .` and `-print0 | xargs -0 -L1 bash -c 'test "$(tail -c 1 "$0")" && echo "No new line at end of $0"'` ) So now I don't know.

Comment: On a **Mac** I changed it slightly to `find . \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.kt" -o -name "*.xml" \) -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' -e '$a\'` because it renamed the files adding `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . \( -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" \) -print | xargs dos2unix {}
```

Comment: `[root@server23 ~]# dos2unix
-bash: dos2unix: command not found`This server doesn't have that nor do I have permission to install dos2unix.

Comment: If you are root you should be able to install it

Comment: Note that this will break badly on files that have spaces in the name or other oddities.  Use "-print0" and "xargs -0" or just use the "-exec dos2unix '{}' +" arguments.  Also, xargs does not take '{}' arguments.

Comment: find . ( -name ".cpp" -o -name ".h" -o -name "*.hpp" ) -print | xargs   echo >> {}

Comment: I have root, but that doesn't mean I have permission from higher-ups. :(

Comment: @Zeno: If you can't install it, you can grab the package that has it, and use "rpm2cpio <PACKAGE-FILENAME | cpio -ivd" to extract it, then just run it from the extracted directory.  For debian packages you need to use "ar xv PACKAGE-FILENAME" which then gives you a tar file that you can extract with "tar xvfz data.tar.gz".  These will result in a "dos2unix" file that you could run with the full path to this extracted file ("find | grep dos2unix" if you can't find it).